# Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04 with [0cf3:3004] Atheros adapter

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, atheros

My laptop, an MSI GS70 Stealth Pro, has build a build in Bluetooth device that Ubuntu seems to not recognize.

When I go to `System Settings > Bluetooth` it says `No Bluetooth adapters found`.

From what I've seen in other threads, I leave here some hopefully helpful info:

**rfkill list:**

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
```

**dmesg | grep Blue:**

```
[    2.951161] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    2.951173] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.951176] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.951177] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.951181] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.959062] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.959064] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.959065] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.959066] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.959066] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.959067] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.959085] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.959093] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    2.959093] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.931392] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.931394] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.931397] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.100415] Bluetooth: Patch file not found ar3k/AthrBT_0x00000200.dfu
[    4.100417] Bluetooth: Loading patch file failed
[    9.725996] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    9.726003] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    9.726006] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   48.509706] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   48.509710] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb :**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Killer N1525 Wireless-AC [1a56:1525]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 05e3:0660 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0660 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 24ae:2003  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: This is a QCA Rome chipset and it has the same bluetooth ID as an older bluetooth that is supported by the kernel.  Qualcomm needs to find a way to fix this.  [This](http://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&m=145684995102375&w=2) is the result from upstream about the device

Comment: I am building a DKMS package for this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem exists because Atheros re-used the chip VID and PID.

See this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1542743)

As a workaround you can patch the `btusb.c` module and change it from ath3k to Rome.

I've built a DKMS package to fix this issue and uploaded it to my PPA.

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1542743-dkms_0.1_all.deb

Install this deb and reboot. This should fix the issue.

Comment: It fixed it right up! I've been without Bluetooth for such a long time. Thank you.

Comment: Update: for some reason, now the bluetooth works but it does not detect any devices. Last system update at 4th July. Should I hope another question?

Comment: Please post output of `dkms status`.

Comment: bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
btusb-lp1542743, 0.1, 4.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia-367, 367.27, 4.4.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia-367, 367.27, 4.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: It looks OK. The problem is not related to kernel. It must be something user space.

Comment: What can I do to fix this? Should I rerun the commands up in the problems description and try to see if something changed?

Comment: It is hard to tell what happened. I added normal support to the module. Nothing has changed in kernel to break it.

Comment: It seams a shutdown and boot (and not a Reboot) did the trick.

Comment: So does it work now? If not add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` to your question. I probably need to remove the ID from `ath3k` too.

Comment: It works now. The major problem now is on sleep or hibernation. Some times everything works fine after wake from sleep, other times it loses it's ability to detect devices.

Comment: Installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 and this deb no longer works.
In the terminal I get this message:  Building initial module for 4.8.0-26-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb-lp1542743/0.1/build/make.log for more information.''

Comment: This deb was never intended for 16.10.

Comment: Then what do I do now?

Comment: Use 16.04 or patch it yourself. I do not support non-LTS releases.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel version 4.4.0-116

My Device is

```
>> lspci -knn | grep bt -A2; lsusb
[..]
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 04ca:3011 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
[..]

>> lspci | grep -i ath
07:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

I had to do the following (adding the Chipset-ID to btusb-driver-patch from Pilot6) to run my Bluetooth Adapter on Acer Aspire V17 Nitro VN7-791G-72FC with Atheros Combo-Card with Bluetooth Chipset Lite-On:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1542743-dkms_0.1_all.deb
mkdir tmp
dpkg-deb -R btusb-lp1542743-dkms_0.1_all.deb tmp
sudo nano tmp/usr/src/btusb-lp1542743-0.1/btusb.c
```

under

```
"static const struct usb_device_id blacklist_table[] = {"
```

adding new line with the following code:

```
{ USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3011), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },
```

after compile, install and reboot:

```
sudo dpkg-deb -b tmp btusb-lp1542743-dkms_0.1_all_modifiedAdd3011.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./btusb-lp1542743-dkms_0.1_all_modifiedAdd3011.deb
sudo reboot
```

now all works fine. :-)
I'm happy.

Comment: Pls explain exactly whats happening here: `{ USB_DEVICE(0x04ca, 0x3011), .driver_info = BTUSB_QCA_ROME },` \n Are you simply prepending `0x` to the ID values of the bluetooth device?

Comment: Not working `Building initial module for 5.0.0-15-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/btusb-lp1542743-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.0.0-15-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb-lp1542743/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package btusb-lp1542743-dkms (--install):
 installed btusb-lp1542743-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 btusb-lp1542743-dkms`

Answer (score 0):

First update firmware for atheros, Only package i found working other than what stated by **Pilot6** in his answer is [here](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-nonfree-arm64/firmware-atheros_20210315-3_all.deb.html), Updating the firmware solves the dropping connection problems too.

Then to reset adaptor without rebooting:

```
sudo rmmod ath3k
```

followed by:

```
sudo modprobe ath3k
```

I can confirm it got working on my laptop after these steps.

In my system, **rfkill** outputs the following:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE                 SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      ideapad_wlan      unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth ideapad_bluetooth unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      phy0              unblocked unblocked
23 bluetooth hci0              unblocked unblocked
```