# Bluetooth (Atheros AR3012 0CF3:3004) does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, atheros

**Edit: This is on a fresh install of the OS.**

## Hardware details

### Laptop

Lenovo Ideapad Z510

### Kernel

```
Linux ip-z510 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Bluetooth

Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 (0cf3:3004) (rev 00.02) **[1]**
Kernel modules in use: bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel **[2]**
Expected kernel module to use: ath3k **[3]**

### WLAN [4]

Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k, wl

#### Sources

**[1]** `usb-devices | awk '/3004/' RS=`:

```
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=03 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0cf3 ProdID=3004 Rev=00.02
S:  Manufacturer=Atheros Communications
S:  Product=Bluetooth USB Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=Alaska Day 2006
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
```

**[2]** I'm not sure how to ascertain which driver is in use. However, `lsmod | grep -i bluetooth` yields:

```
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
```

**[3]**

- According to https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/ath3k?s[]=ar3012, a combination of these files must be used, though I am not certain which ones would apply for my case:

  ```
  For AR3012, you can find the “AthrBT_0x01020200.dfu” and “ramps_0x01020200_26.dfu” or “ramps_0x01020200_40.dfu” on the linux-firmware git tree:
  git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/ar3k/
  ```
- `modinfo ath3k` and `modinfo ath3k | grep 3004` confirm my expectation:

  ```
  filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-59-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
  firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
  license:        GPL
  version:        1.0
  description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
  author:         Atheros Communications
  alias:          usb:v0CF3p3004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
  alias:          usb:v04CAp3004d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
  ```

**[4]** `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k, wl
```

## Additional notes/details:

- Loading `ath3k` on boot via `/etc/modules` OR via `sudo modprobe ath3k` does not make BT work. `dmesg | tail` only reports:

  ```
  [   17.178240] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
  ```
- `dmesg | grep -i blue`:

  ```
  [    1.621634] usb 3-7: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
  [   16.828268] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
  [   16.828279] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  [   16.828282] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  [   16.828284] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  [   16.828288] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  [   27.793692] usb 3-7: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
  [   36.501132] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  [   36.501134] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  [   36.501138] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
  [   46.280055] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c38 tx timeout
  [   48.284048] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c39 tx timeout
  [   50.288051] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c05 tx timeout
  [   50.739075] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
  [   50.739086] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
  [   50.739090] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
  [   52.292034] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c16 tx timeout
  ```
- `rfkill list; hciconfig hci0; systemctl status bluetooth.service`

  ```
  0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  2: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  3: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
      BD Address: A4:DB:30:D1:E5:52  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
      DOWN 
      RX bytes:904 acl:0 sco:0 events:38 errors:0
      TX bytes:392 acl:0 sco:0 commands:47 errors:9

  ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-01-21 13:37:47 IST; 39min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 896 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─896 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

  Jan 21 13:38:01 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
  Jan 21 13:38:04 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
  Jan 21 13:38:14 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
  Jan 21 13:42:55 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
  Jan 21 13:42:55 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.53 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
  Jan 21 13:43:08 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
  Jan 21 13:43:10 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.100 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
  Jan 21 13:43:10 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.100 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
  Jan 21 13:43:21 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
  Jan 21 13:46:32 ip-z510 bluetoothd[896]: Failed to set mode: Failed (0x03)
  ```

## Behavior

- The bluetooth icon may or may not load in the tray on login.
- The bluetooth toggle may or may not work.
- When the bluetooth toggle works, nothing is found on a search. Tried my phone and bluetooth audio.

## Similar questions

[Bluetooth (Atheros AR3012) not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832438/bluetooth-atheros-ar3012-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) -- no answer

[Bluetooth not working in Ubuntu 16.04 with [0cf3:3004] Atheros adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791584/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-16-04-with-0cf33004-atheros-adapter) -- Pilot6's solution does not work (this, I attempted before the clean OS reinstall yesterday).

Comment: Please uninstall Pilot6's fix as that should only be used with wifi cards that use the ath10k_pci module then do a complete shutdown and reboot

Comment: I just reinstalled the OS yesterday. Nothing in the kernel is touched at this point, apart from trying to load `ath3k` module and unloading it.

Comment: The firmware is actually included in Ubuntu.  Strange that ath3k isn't loading on its own as it loads the firmware.  Check `dmesg | grep xhci_hcd` for any strange disconnects

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any strange disconnects. I do, however, see this for `usb 3-7` -- `[    1.492050] usb 3-7: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd`

Comment: It looks like some custom `btusb` module is loaded that defines the chip as QCA_ROME.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `dkms status; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; cat /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep ath3k`  There has been a few reports of issues with this device on askubuntu but if Pilot6 is correct there should be a firmware error from btusb.  I know there was an issue with the firmware loading a couple years back that was fixed by delaying the firmware upload

Comment: Something very curious. Reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04, upgraded packages, auto installed ubuntu-drivers, restarted. Bluetooth is now working! On 3 out of 4 restarts, it worked fine without the need to fiddle with anything. Interestingly, it is now also working on my elementaryOS install (which too is a fresh install).

It did not work on 4.4.0-36 but did on 4.4.0-59; although other packages are more likely to have influenced it that the kernel update itself.

Comment: I will give this a try for 3-4 days and report back on its consistency.

Comment: Moving this to the Ubuntu Forums -- as that seems like a more appropriate place. If and when solved, I shall post the solution here as well. Until then, it seems like this will need some more discussion back and forth. Here's the forum link: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2350200&p=13597659

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problems, I've found this form which is worked for me (https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=4375)

in short:

try

```sh
sudo bluethoothcli
```

if it says: "no default controller" then this solution might work for you:

1. download the listed drivers here (https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/tree/master/brcm)
2. make a directory called BCM.hcd

```sh
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd
```

3. copy drivers to that folder like

```sh
sudo cp BCM43142A0* /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd
```

completely shutdown your computer, then turn on and try

```sh
sudo bluethoothcli
```

if you were able to type

```sh
list # or 
scan on
```

and it print controller name or found some devices then it's solved for you.

Comment: This solution is for Broadcom devices. You never had "the same problem".

Comment: I have "Bluetooth (Atheros AR3012)" but I really don't know how it works

Comment: If you have an Atheros device, installing Broadcom firmware makes no sense.