# Bluetooth Driver not found/working for the AR3012 Bluetooth Driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, bluetooth, atheros

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my MSI GS70 2QD laptop with the 4.13.0-32-generic kernel.

The problem that I am having is that my computer has bluetooth capabilities, but the kernel is not able to find the bluetooth drivers.

When I run`rfkill list`, the output is:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

when I run `lsusb`, the output is:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1770:ff00  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:055c Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The `lspci` ouputs:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM87 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204M [GeForce GTX 965M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5249 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 13)
05:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
```

I have read many different articles on this exact problem with the AR3012 driver, but I cannot seem to get any of the different ways to work, so either I am doing something wrong, or I am not fully understanding what I am supposed to do.

If there is any more information that you need from me to help me out, please let me know.

Edit:

The `dkms status` results are:

```
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-112-generic, x86_64: installed
bluetooth-3004, 0.1, 4.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.13.0-31-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.13.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.4.0-112-generic, x86_64: installed
```

And, the `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` results are:

```
[    0.073749] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.023535] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    1.578877] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[    7.833099] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    7.833110] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    7.833112] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    7.833114] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    7.833120] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.123289] ath10k_pci 0000:05:00.0: firmware ver SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 api 5 features ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad crc32 10bf8e08
[   10.038096] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.038097] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.038100] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Edit 2:

The output for `echo -e "power on\n scan on\n quit" |bluetoothctl` is as follows:

```
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#  scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#  quit
```

Edit 3:

The output for `modinfo btusb | grep file` is as follows:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/btusb.ko
```

Edit 4:

The output for `lsmod | grep blue` is as follows:

```
bluetooth             544768  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was caused by Atheros using the same ID for 2 different bluetooth devices, similar to https://askubuntu.com/a/791590/300665
I patched the 4.13 source code for your bluetooth device, in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-4.13-ath3004-rome.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-4.13-ath3004-rome
sudo dkms install bluetooth-3004/0.1
```

Edit also do `echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
Reboot

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I just tried your fix, and is still did not work for me.  I even copy and pasted your terminal scripts just to make sure I did not make a typo.  

Are there any other reason why this problem may occur?

Comment: Give me results for `dkms status` and `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`  I am sure I got the patches correct but the dkms part I am not sure about

Comment: I have added the output for these two commands to my main question above labeled as an edit.

Comment: Try in terminal `echo -e "power on\n scan on\n quit" |bluetoothctl`

Comment: I posted the output above in Edit 2

Comment: I'm sorry, I just made a stupid mistake,  I had my USB dongle plugged in on the USB while I ran those last 2 outputs, give me a minute so that I can update the 2 updates I have on the question.

Comment: I have just updated the command outputs with me having the USB Bluetooth unplugged.

Comment: Post results for `modinfo btusb | grep file`

Comment: I have added the output to this command under Edit 3.

Comment: I just did the edit that you made with the echo "blacklist ath3k...." and it still did not work.

Comment: Any results from `rfkill list`

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response, I just did the rfkill list command and I get the same result that I posted in my initial question above.

Comment: What about results for `lsmod | grep blue`

Comment: I have added this ouput under Edit 4 above.

Comment: I would suggest using a 4.4 kernel and trying Pilot6's answer from the link in my answer

Comment: ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for bluetooth-3004: 0.1 not found